# JMeter preprocessor called multiple times

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 nested Loop Controllers with 3 jsr223 groovy preprocessors

```
Loop1 (2 loops)
  |_ preprocessor1
  |_Loop2 (3 loops)
      |_preprocessor2
      |_Loop3 (4 loops)
          |_preprocessor3
          |_HttpRequest
```

To keep things simple the thread group runs with 1 thread.

So I would expect 2*3*4 = 24 http requests. This is what I get. However for every htttp request...

preprocessor1
 preprocessor2
 preprocessor3

..all get called. Why?

What I want is preprocessor1 run for each iteration of loop1, preprocessor2 run for each iteration of loop2 and preprocessor3 run for each iteration of loop3, which to me is logical especially when you view the nested tree in the GUI.

Comment: I started to use Jmeter yesterday so I apologise if my question is dumb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Preprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#preprocessors) are hierarchial, meaning effect samplers in their hierarchy or below.

> If a Pre-Processor is attached to a Sampler element, then it will execute just prior to that sampler element running.

If you want it to execute only on their position, you can put it under a Sampler, as [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) which will have no effect

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. You got me thinking though. In my case I was using a jsr223 groovy preprocessor. I no longer use a pre-processor and just use the jsr223 sampler and I now get the desired behaviour. Thanks for quick reply!!